# How to add js code programmaticaly?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, formik

I am generating a (formik) form programmatically.
The following works well.

```
var coolist = ReferralColDef.map((el) =>
        <div> 
          <label>{el.Header}</label> 
          <Field type={el.type} name={el.accessor} placeholder={el.Header} />
        </div>
      )
```

How can I add the following line inside the div tag, right after the Field tag?
Or is there a better way of doing this?

```
{touched.{el.accessor} && errors.{el.accessor} && <p>{errors.{el.accessor}}</p>}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly confused but sounds like you want something like this...
"inside div but after field"..

```
var coolist = ReferralColDef.map((el) =>
        <div> 
          <label>{el.Header}</label> 
          <Field type={el.type} name={el.accessor} placeholder={el.Header} />
          {touched.[el.accessor] && errors.[el.accessor] && <p>{errors.[el.accessor]}</p>}
        </div>
      )
```

if you're talking about actually in styled output like you want the text to sit below, display:block should work in most cases

Comment: This will not work because the code withing the curly brackets gets executed
This is exactly my problem... How can I retrieve it from map without being exucted
within the map?

Comment: oh sorry it would be touched[el.accessor] square bracket